# How do I solve this equation, which includes logarithms,

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

So I’m having difficulties with an equation involving a $\log(x)$. I was actually trying to solve a physics problem, but since this is an issue relating maths I came here.

Anyway, my equation is:
$-9 = 102 - 20\log(r) - \frac{r}{500}$

And I have to find the value of $r$.
The thing is, I keep getting stuck when trying to solve it. And I’m not even sure I have the right equation to begin with - does mine make sense? Does it work? And if so, how can I find the value of $r$?

Comment: It doesn't solve analytically, however, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+-9+%3D+102+-+20*log%28x%29+-+x%2F500) gives the only answer is $r\approx 250.864646167580$.

Comment: Are you familiar with numerical methods?

Comment: It can be solved in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @Alexey Burdin Thanks for that website, and it seems that I had the right equation, because r being around 250.86 makes sense in the situation I was trying to analyze. The thing is, the website doesn’t indicate how it arrived to that solution - I’m guessing I’ll follow the method suggested by metamorphy.
Anton Vrdoljak - No, I’m not familiar with numerical analysis. 
metamorphy - Thank you for the Lambert W function, I will try to see if I understand how this works!

Comment: I don't find the W function very useful.  Equations with the variable in both and exponent and outside usually call for a numeric solution.  Any numeric solver will make short work of this.